# Accessing extra selected columns from a resultset inside Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, resultset, dbix-class, template-toolkit

```
my $rs = schema->resultset('Table1')->search(
   undef,
   {
      join => 'relationship_table2',
      '+select' => ['relationship_table2.fk_id','relationship_table2.order],
      '+as'     => ['fk_id', 'order'],
   }
);
```

Inside of template (test.tt):

```
[% WHILE (result=rs.next) %]
table1.id    [% result.id   %] <!-- prints primary key for table1 -->
table1.name  [% result.name %] <!-- prints name of item for table1 -->
table2.order [% result.order %] <!-- doesn't work -->
table2.order [% result.relationship_table2.order %] <!-- doesn't work -->
[% END %]
```

I don't know how to access the extra selected items in resultset passed to the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of the `+as` option alongside `+select` then you can use `result.get_column('column_name')` in your template.  You could also define an accessor in your result class to make the get_column call for you.